Who were the oldest US Presidential nominees?
I've seen some claims online that Trump (2024) and Biden (2020) were the oldest people to ever be nominated for president by a US political party.
However a bit of research seems to show that this isn't true. For example, Peter Cooper (1876:Greenback party) was 85, and William Hope Harvey (1932:Liberty party) was 81.
Who were the oldest presidential nominees, and where do Trump and Biden rank on this list?

Just to clarify, neither man was a nominee of a major party, (or even a very prominent minor party), so their "campaigns" were entirely symbolic.

@T.E.D. - Peter Cooper got 1% of the popular vote. I think as far as third party candidates go in the US that's fairly significant.

Depends on what you consider to be "significant" I guess. In 2020 Jo Jorgensen got a bit over 1% of the vote. Do you know who that is off the top of your head? I didn't before hitting the 2020 Election WP page.

@T.E.D. To be fair, in modern politics, people rarely remember which politician they ate for breakfast.  Wait, I must be mixing metaphors...

It seems you have the correct candidates for being the oldest nominations. There was one other (than the two you mentioned), for a total of three nominees, older than Trump and Biden.. Although nominees in their 70s is not all that uncommon, and not even a recent phenomenon to boot!



Name
Age at Nomination
Election Year
Pop. vote (%)




Peter Cooper
85
1876
0.99


William Hope Harvey
81
1932
0.13


John M. Palmer
79
1896
0.96


Donald Trump
78
2024
TBD


Joe Biden*
78
2020
51.31


Neal Dow
76
1880
0.11


Donald Trump
74
2020
46.85


Ralph Nader
74
2008
0.56


Samuel Adams
74
1796
n/a†


Bob Dole
73
1996
40.71


Ronald Reagan*
73
1984
58.77


John Bidwell
73
1892
2.24


John McCain
72
2008
45.65


Donald Trump*
70
2016
46.09


Ralph Nader
70
2004
0.38


* Indicates Winner


† Predates 12th Amendment;   no pop. vote in several states



Joe Biden was oldest general election winner at 78 in 2020. This may potentially turn into a close second, if the current Republican nominee goes on to win the general election this cycle.
Note 1: ages may be +/- 1 year based on month of birth. I didn't go as far as to compare the exact date of nomination or election date versus birthdate.
Note 2: I did not check if all these candidates were on the ballot in all states at the time of general election or if they withdrew prior.
Note 3: I chose 70 as a cutoff point as the list would start to be cumbersome after that.

Also, I think I see how the non-major party names were selected (basically, if it made the "other" candidates list on the linked WP page), but it would be nice if we could figure out what WP's critera for inclusion there is. If not, perhaps just add a note to the answer that it was based on who the WP editors decided to consider a candidate or an "other" candidate when it was compiled? (likely that's the best that can be done)

Oh, and as for note 2, Harvey was not on the ballot in all states. His "party" was basically his own invention and it died with him (less than 4 years later). Neither was Nader (my mom was a plaintiff in the unsuccessful lawsuit to get him on the ballot in Oklahoma)

@T.E.D. the talk page says it's candidates that got at least 0.1% of the popular vote

Also note that Harry Byrd was not the nominee of any party and did not campaign for the presidency.  He's on the Wikipedia list because he got votes from unpledged & faithless electors in the electoral college.

I took the liberty of adding the percentages of the popular vote received, in order to help contextualize whether these candidates were serious contenders or not.  Feel free to revert the edit if you see fit.

@MichaelSeifert - Damn. I was making an edit to the same table to indicate which candidates both received no EVs and were not on the ballot on all states, and your conflicting update aced me out by 1 minute. :-P   I could try to merge them, but IMHO the resulting table would be too squished and far too busy. I may just post it in another answer.

@MichaelSeifert - As for the Samuel Adams note, it wasn't just "not all states", but rather only 2 states had any kind of popular vote at that time. He got EV's though, so I think its fair to consider him a real-ish candidate. There was actually another election on this list (Cooper in 1876) where Colorado didn't have a popular vote, as they'd been admitted to the nation too recently to organize one in time. Cooper got no EV's, and was not even on the ballot on all the other states though.

I think I'm with @MichaelSeifert that Byrd does not belong on a list of oldest nominees, since he was not nominated by any party that year. Deleting that one in the interest of factuality.

@T.E.D."On the ballot in all states" is a pretty tough requirement; Harry Truman wouldn't qualify.

@bof - I'll admit its not much more permissive than "the two major parties" these days, given the current attitude of states like Oklahoma (Party has to get a huge % of registered voter signatures, or have gotten a sizeable % of the vote in the previous quadrennial general election). Still, its a bar you often hear being reported about candidates in the media, so it has some public mindshare. I think the Libertarian Party is the only 3rd party that regularly reaches it.

There's a good answer to this already that the OP is quite happy with. However, I strongly feel that the framing is vague and misleading. So I'd like to see us have an answer that's a bit more explicit.
Oldest Major Party Nominees:
Below are the oldest people to have recieved a nomination from what was at the time one of the 2 major parties.



Name
Age at Nomination
Election Year




Donald Trump
78
2024


Joe Biden
78
2020


Donald Trump
74
2020


Bob Dole
73
1996


Ronald Reagan
73
1984


John McCain
72
2008


Donald Trump
70
2016



Oldest Serious Nominees
Where a "serious nominee" is someone who was nominated by a party, actually mounted a campaign, and either received Electoral College votes or was on the ballot in all states that had ballots at the time.



Name
Age at Nomination
Election Year




Donald Trump
78
2024


Joe Biden
78
2020


Donald Trump
74
2020


Bob Dole
73
1996


Ronald Reagan
73
1984


John McCain
72
2008


Donald Trump
70
2016



Note that this is the same list
There are a couple of people who nearly made this list. Samuel Adams did receive electoral votes. However, US political parties did not give out "nominations" at that time, and he was a member of the same party as multiple other people who received Electoral College votes. Likewise, Harry Byrd in 1960 also received electoral votes without the benefit of any party's nomination.
Oldest Party Nominees to get 1%
This is the same list as the above 2, with the addition of 73 year old John Bidwell, who got a whopping 2.24% in the election of 1892 as the nominee of the Prohibition Party. That slots him in the table right under Ronald Reagan. He received no Electoral College votes, and was not on the ballot in all states.
Oldest Party Nominee
I don't think we know this one, and I don't know that we can know it. Every cycle hundreds of people "announce" they are running for President, and make themselves "parties" to make it look like a real campaign. For instance, comedian Pat Paulsen started a "campaign" as part of a comedy bit on the Smothers Brothers show, and kept doing it for multiple cycles thereafter. It was a good bit, allowing him to lampoon politicians during election seasons (a much-needed service).
Another such perennial candidate is Vermin Supreme, who has run as the nominee of the "Good Humor Party" and the "Free Pony Party". He's 64 now, and will presumably keep running in the future, health allowing.
Other people often mount symbolic campaigns to get media awareness for favorite causes. This was certainly the case for Willilam Hope Harvey, mentioned in the question. His "Liberty Party" was created to promote his own economic theories. (Note that his party merged with another during the election, so he ran as an independent, not a party nominee)
Then some people (actually, a whole lot of people) are just downright mentally unwell. I'm not adding examples here so as not to signal boost them.

Vermin Supreme? Isn't that the one Trump considers his opponent? Or was it the other way round ...

@HagenvonEitzen - When V.S. runs in major party primaries, its usually the Democratic Party. That of course doesn't mean his platform has a thing to do with that party. The same could be said for the late Lyndon Larouche.
